# Why is sys.stdout.write called twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, stdout

I'm trying to log all my prints to a log file (and add a timestamp before the actual message, only in the log file), but I cannot figure out why `sys.stdout.write` is called twice.

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename="Default.log"):
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "w")

    def write(self, message):
        self.stdout.write(message)
        time_stamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        self.log.write(f"{time_stamp} - {message}")
        self.log.flush()
    
    def flush(self):
        pass

sys.stdout = Logger("log_file.txt")
print("Hello world !")
```

Output from terminal:

```
Hello World !
```

Output in log_file.txt:

```
2021-04-19 18:43:14.800691 - Hello world !2021-04-19 18:43:14.800735 -
```

What am I missing here? The write method is called again after the `self.log.flush()` has been called, but here `message=''`.

If I neglect the time_stamp variable it works like a charm, e.g calling `self.log.write(message)`.

I could of course just check if message is empty, but I would really like to understand my problem here!

### **My solution**

@iBug gave me the answer! I didn't know that print did work this way: one write call for the data and one write call for the `end` keyword which is `\n` as default.

My solution was to add a variable `self._hidden_end` to mthe `Logger` class that is initiated to 0 and then toggles everytime `write` is called to check it I should add a time stampe before writing to the log or not.

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename="Default.log"):
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "w")
        self._hidden_end = 0

    def write(self, message):
        self.stdout.write(message)
        if not self._hidden_end:
            time_stamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            message = f"{time_stamp} - {message}"
        self._hidden_end ^= 1
        self.log.write(message)
        self.log.flush()
    
    def flush(self):
        pass

sys.stdout = Logger("log_file.txt")
print("Hello world !")
```

Any thoughts on my solution above are welcome! :)

Comment: I'm afraid that's how `print()` works - once for the data and once for the newline (i.e. the hidden `print(end='\n')`)

Comment: Thanks alot - that explains my problem :)

Comment: @amkleist you should remove your solution from your question and post it as an answer. Also, "any thoughts on my solution" is too broad. Stack Overflow is for _specific_ questions about your code. For general code-review, [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place, but remember to check their [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guidelines first

Comment: @iBug please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ That's just a (hopefully correct) speculation which I made without checking the code or searching for any references. That's IMO a good reason to leave a potential yet incomplete "answer" as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your perceived results indicates that [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) calls `file.write` twice: Once for the data and once for the "end content", which is a newline by default and can be overridden with the `end` keyword argument. Relevant [source code lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/68ba0c67cac10c2545ea3b62d8b161e5b3594edd/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2020) confirm this speculation.

However, this is not something you should rely on. It's entirely implementation details, may be different for another implementation (e.g. PyPy) and may change at any time without notice, not to mention that overriding builtins is another bad practice. You should avoid this kind of practice without a compelling reason *not to* modify other parts of the code to use your custom logging facility.

Should you really need to do monkey-patching, it's safer to override the `print()` function since it has a defined, reliable interface. You can import the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins) and assign your new print function to `builtins.print`, maintaining control over calls to your logging handler.